# Alter option value of HTML.Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a HTML helper for a dropdown list (shown below)

View:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("LocationID", null, new {id ="Location" })
```

Controller:

```
  ViewBag.LocationID = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationID", "LocationName", job.LocationID);
```

Now when this renders in google chrome, it presents it like the following

```
    <select id="Location" name="LocationID">
<option selected="selected" value="2">Cleanroom</option>
<option value="1">Head Board Assembly</option>
<option value="5">Light Testing</option>
<option value="3">Mechanical Assembly</option>
<option value="6">Picture Testing</option>
<option value="4">Quality Control</option>
<option value="7">Shipping</option>
</select>
```

How do i alter the option value from numeric to the actual values, so for example:

option value =1  should actually equal-  option value:Head Board Assembly

The reason for this is for a jquery and to save further confusion down the line id like the value to be the actual value, saving anyone working on this code in future the frustration of going back and forth between linking numeric values to the actual value

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why is this tagged jQuery when it is .Net issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you have to pass `LocationName` property in both ValueField and TextField in the `SelectList` Constructor:

```
new SelectList(db.Locations,"LocationName", "LocationName", job.LocationName);
```

but you should be using `LocationID` as value of Dropdownlist.

Comment: thanks @Ehsan :) clearly works but of course disconnects the LocationID :) least ill know in future

Answer (score 0):

you have to passe the location Name twice , not LocationID and locationName

```
ViewBag.LocationID = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationName", "LocationName", job.LocationID);
```